# How to render images/textures in shape/polygon form?

Tags: c++, rendering, sfml

I'm working with SFML right now, and upon finishing the tutorials I still do not know how to give a shape a texture or image -- not just a solid color/outline.

The only thing I know can take an image is a sprite, but thats *way* to simple, as it only allows you to render rectangular images in a rectangluar way!

**What are the techniques for rendering images onto shapes, and *only* inside the shape?** It would be great if some of you could provide some resources or SFML-specific stuff!

Comment: Griffin, I answered this when you asked on SO. The answer is the same as Josh's...

Comment: i put the answer on both sites right away, hoping i'd get an answer on 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly using SFML. It looks like the [shape](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Shape.php) class will not support texture mapping; allegedly it is a planned feature for the next version ([discussion](http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=31705&sid=52d89587c868fd0c9e96d8ae4c776219)).

Depending on the kind of visual effect you are going for -- I didn't find your description entirely clear -- you could do something like using a shape to mask a sprite, as described [in this post](http://pjmendes.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-do-masking-in-sfml-with-opengl.html) (scroll down a ways, there's an image with the example result), or you could use OpenGL directly to render a series of texture-mapped triangles with the image mapped appropriately using texture coordinates.

Note that while sprites are rectangular in their nature, you can achieve the visual result of a non-rectangular image by including transparency (typically via the alpha channel of the image), and that may be all you need to achieve your desired visual result.

Answer (score 3):

SFML has been updated since this question was originally answered and you can now add textures to shapes easily. The shape class has the `setTexture()` and `setTextureRect()` methods. `setTexture()` takes a pointer to an `sf::Texture`. See the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Shape.php).

```
Sf::Texture texture;
if (!texture.loadFromFile("mytexture.png"))
{
    std::cerr << "failed to load";
}
sf::RectangleShape myRect{ sf::Vector2f(width, height) };
myRect.setTexture(&texture);
myRect.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect( x, y, width, height ));
```